Do I need underscore in primary constructor parameters' names?
What is right:
class MyClass(IInjectable _injectable) {}

or
class MyClass(IInjectable injectable) {}

On the one hand, we have private field. On the other hand, this is constructor parameter's name.

It is a naming convention and nothing else.

It's a convention. You can use whatever you want and is syntactically allowed. So, it's not a right or wrong question. Better "if I want to follow standard c# convention, is A or B applicable?", maybe.

Naming Parameters

Primary constructor parameters should best not be regarded as "implicit private fields", they are not members of the class. Hence, your first notation makes little sense.
See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/primary-constructors for details.
